# Compare 2 arrays and return true if ANY values match

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays, for example:

Array1: [One, Two, Three, Four, Five]
Array2: [Three, Five]

I need to have a function which returns true if any values in Array2 match any values in Array1.

I have tried:

```
var compareArray = $.inArray(Array1, Array2);
```

but this always returns '-1'.

Comment: That's because the $.inArray() function takes a value and an Array.  Not an entire Array and the other array.  So, you'd have to loop through the Array (using a for loop) to pass each value to compare against the other array.

Comment: OK how would i loop through an array and compare each value with the other array? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is another questions that you can use as a guide to your solution:

[Comparing two arrays in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856846/comparing-two-arrays-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a brute force algorithm if you are only working with small arrays. Something like the following should work.

```js
function findMatch(arr1, arr2) {
  for (i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
  
  return false
}
```